# hide menus based on user login , logout in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have ionic app with side menus having home , login , dashboard, logout(items).

I am using server api to login user , i want when used is logged in side menu items login to be not there and dashboard, logout to be added , same way when user logouts he can see login but not logout and accoun menu .

Below is my code :

http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/bEjGNa

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>Ionic page</title>
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//fabricjs.com/lib/fabric_with_gestures.js"></script>
  
  
   
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeTabCtrl">


<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right"> </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="right">
   <div class="list">
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"><i class="icon ion-email"></i> Check mail</a>
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#login" ng-hide="show_menu" > <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working" ></i>Login</a> 
    <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#account" ng-hide="show_menu"> <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i> Account</a> 

   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#" ng-hide="show_menu"> <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i> Logout</a> 
   </div>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>  


<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-positive tabs-top tabs-top-my tabs-icon-only" animation="fade-in-out">

        <ion-tab title="tab1" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/tab1">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab1-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab2" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/tab2">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab2-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="tab3" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab3">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab3-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="tab4" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab4">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab4-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="tab5" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab5">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab5-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab title="tab6" icon="ion-android-apps" ng-click="toggleRightSideMenu()"  ui-sref="tabs.tab6">
         <ion-nav-view name="tab6-tab"></ion-nav-view>

        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>
  <ion-footer-bar  class="bar-footer btn-footer bar-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-positive" ng-click='next()'> View cart Page </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-calm"> View checkout page </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
    </script> 
<script id="templates/tab1.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab1">
  <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
   <div class="row p0">
  
 
   </div>
  </div>

      </ion-view>
</script> 
  
  
  
  
  
  
<script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
 user name is {{user.name}}
</script>  
  
  
 <script id="templates/login.html" type="text/ng-template">
   
   <ion-view view-title="Buy Now" nav-bar-class="bar-balanced" cache-view="false">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
      <button class="button button-clear button-light" ui-sref='tabs.tab1'><i class="ion-chevron-left"></i></button>
      <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
 </ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-content class="padding">

 <div class="list">
<form method="post" action="" id="form-id">

   <label class="item item-input">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username">
   </label>
   <label class="item item-input">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password">
   </label>
</form>

   
 </div>
 
 <div class="row">
  <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="signIn()">
    Login
  </button>
 </div>


 </ion-content>
 

</ion-view>
  
  </script>
  
  
  
 
<script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script> 
  <script id="templates/next.html" type="text/ng-template">


    <ion-view view-title="View Cart" nav-bar-class="bar-balanced">
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-bar>
 <ion-content class="padding">
  
    clicked id :
   <p>
  <a class="button icon ion-home" href="#/tab/home"> Home</a>
  <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Scientific Facts</a>
   </p>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
    
</script> 
<script>
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionicApp.controllers', 'ngAnimate']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.tab1', {
      url: "/tab1",
      views: {
        'tab1-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab1.html",
          controller: 'Tab1Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: "/login",
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
   controller: "login"
    }).state('account', {
      url: "/account",
      templateUrl: "templates/account.html",
   controller: "account"
    })
  .state('next', {
      url: "/next",
      templateUrl: "templates/next.html",
      controller: "NextController",
  params: {
   clickedid: null
  }
    })
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/tab1");

}).controller('account', function ($scope,$http,$ionicPopup) {

}).controller('login', function ($scope,$http,$ionicPopup) {

 $scope.signIn = function () {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
  $scope.show_menu = true;
  var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
   title: 'sucess',
   template: 'now logout and account should show'
    });
 
 };
 
}).controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $state) {
$scope.show_menu = false;
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
  $scope.toggleRightSideMenu = function() {
   console.log('rigth open')
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
  };
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
  $scope.next = function(){
    $state.transitionTo('next');   
  }
}).controller("NextController", function($scope){
    $scope.showAlert = function(){ alert("I'm a modal window!") }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not exactly sure which elements you wish to show or hide but unless I miss understand you, why not just use ng-hide or ng-show as follows:

```
<ion-side-menus ng-hide="!show_menu">
</ion-side-menus>
```

or

```
<ion-side-menus ng-show="show_menu">
</ion-side-menus>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

Comment: see when not logged in hide account and logout , when logged in hide login

Comment: bro just goto login , press submit after submit click i set value of show menu to true , but still i am able to see login in sidebar

Comment: Ahh ok. I'd guess the scope of the Login controller is probably different to the HomeTabCtrl so your page scope isnt changeing.

Answer (score 0):

i didn't go over your code, but you can just make a script that checks if user is logged in / logged out and just hides the the Login or Logout link.

for example in your CSS make a class

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

then make a script that checks if user is logged in and hides if he is

```
if (userLoggedIn){
   $(loginButton).addClass("hidden");
   $(logoutButton).removeClass("hidden");
}
else{
   $(logoutButton).addClass("hidden");
   $(loginButton).removeClass("hidden");
}
```

where loginButton holds the id of the login button and same for logoutButton.

you get the drift i hope.

Comment: bro i want to use angular js , i can do it using jquery

Answer (score 0):

First change the html with the following

```
<a class="item item-icon-left" href="#login" ng-hide="show_menu" > <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working" ></i>Login</a> 
<a class="item item-icon-left" href="#account" ng-show="show_menu"> <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i> Account</a> 

<a class="item item-icon-left" href="#" ng-show="show_menu"> <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i> Logout</a>
```

and then in the `login` controller initialize the `show_menu` variable before defining the `signIn` function. like

```
.controller('login', function ($scope,$http,$ionicPopup) {
    $scope.show_menu = false;
    $scope.signIn = function () {
       //your code
       $scope.show_menu = true;
       //your other code

    };

})
```

Answer (score 0):

here's what you can do:

1. add this function to your js

`function toggleHide(){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-hide");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].onclick = function(){
            var containerid = this.getAttribute('data-hide-container');
            document.getElementById(containerid).classList.toggle('ng-hide');
        }
    }
}`

I made that using pure js so is not gonna be a problem.

2. add this to your css:

`.ng-hide{
  display:none;
}`

3. you can use that like this:

`<button class="toggle-hide" data-hide-container="searchMapContainer"></button>`

**I created the function having the data-hide-container as an ID of the element that you want to hide. You can change that to use class instead if necessary.**

4. call the function *toggleHide()* inside the controller you want to use.

I hope it helps.